# Select the index which has the most number of prefixes among others?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdvector, prefix

I have a number of sequences of 0 and 1 and I want to find the one that has maximum number of other sequences that form a prefix to the current one.

Example:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> sequence={{1,1},{1},{0,1,0,1},{1,1,0}}
```

{1,1} has only 1 prefix namely {1}.

But {1,1,0} has 2 prefixes {1,1} and {1}. Since it hast the most prefix count, I want to select index 3 of the `sequence.` I can do it with nested loops but it consumes so much time since I have to deal with sequences of size *512*. Thanks for any help.

What I have done so far:

```
bool isPrefixOf(std::vector<int> current, std::vector<int> other){
  if (other.size()>current.size())
      return false;
  for (int i=0; i<other.size(); ++i) {
      if (other[i] != current[i]) 
          return false;
    }
  return true; 
}

int len = sequence.size();
int max = 0;
int selected = -1;
int prefix_count;
for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
    prefix_count = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<len; j++){
      if(isPrefixOf(sequence[i],sequence[j])) ++prefix_count;
    }
    if(prefix_count >= max){
      max = prefix_count;
      selected = i;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You'd have `selected = i;`, i. e. the *index* where you found the maximum.

Comment: @Aconcagua Ahh, true.

Comment: Sorry, have been inattendent (four in the morning here...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your double loop results in an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm. You can get an O(n) one, if you build a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (binary in your case) as follows:

- For each single sequence, iterate over the values, follow the left child on 0 and the right child on 1. Create new children, if not present.
- If the sequence is finished, increment the current node (whether leaf or not!). Variant: If you don't want to count duplicates, just set the node value to 1 (whether it was before or not).
- Of interest are only the leaves, as any parent node shares the prefixes with the leaf, but is itself a prefix, so the leaf will have (at least) one more prefix.
- For each leaf, sum up the values on the path from the root to the leaf.
- The leaf with the maximum marks the sequence you are after; you can remember the maximum right while calculating the sums, so you don't have to walk the tree twice

For your given example, the tree would look like this:

```
      [0] (root, always 0)
     /   \
    /(0)  \(1)
   /       \
 [0]       [1] (one sequence finished here!)
   \         \
    \(1)      \(1)
     \         \
     [0]       [1]
     /          /
    /(0)       /(0)
   /          / 
 [0]        [1]<3>
   \
    \(1)
     \
     [1]<1>
```

Including the leaf in the sum will correctly consider duplicates in the leaves. This will include the sequence forming the path to the leave itself (interpretation: each sequence is a prefix to itself), but as this is the case for *every* leaf, you get an offset of 1 for all equally, so this has no influence on the maximum, which you are after...

You might additionally store the index of the sequence leading to the node inside the node for quicker access in the original vector.